# Access ApplicationSessionState in .net core microservice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, session-state

I have an ASP.NET MVC application running on .NET 4.8 which creates and shares a JWT token and maintains user session.

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API micro service which is validating the JWT token using `RSACryptoServiceProvider`.

Is there a way to in .NET Core to check if user is still logged in?

**Note**: in the ASP.NET MVC application we are checking using the `ApplicationSessionState`.

Answer (score 1):

Inside asp.net core, normally, we will use authentication middleware with authentication service like JWT authentication service to check the user is authenticated or not.

Then inside the controller, we could check the user state by using user's claim and `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` to check if the user is login or not.

In short, inside asp.net core, if the client send the request with right authentication token, and this token passed the authentication middleware, it will set the IsAuthenticated property to ture which means the user has login in.

If you want to use custom logic to check the token, one possible way is using the asp.net core AuthorizationHandler.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

custom requirement class：

```
public class CustomAuthenticationRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
}
```

Custom handler:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<CustomAuthenticationRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, CustomAuthenticationRequirement requirement)
    {
        //your previous codes to check the user
        if (context.Resource is HttpContext authorizationFilterContext)
        {
            if (authorizationFilterContext.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
            {
                    //
                    var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "aa")
                };

                    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "custom");
                    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                    authorizationFilterContext.User = principal;

                    context.Succeed(requirement);
                //}
            }
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private bool IsAuthorizedUser(string username, string password)
    {
        return username == "test" && password == "pass";
    }
}
```

Program.cs, for 3.1 you replace the `builder.Services.AddAuthorization` to `services.AddAuthorization`.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CustomAuthentication", policy =>
        policy.Requirements.Add(new CustomAuthenticationRequirement()));
});

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, CustomAuthenticationHandler>();
```

Result:

[image]